# How to get custom customer attribute file type value in Edit Account Information section in magento2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

I create Installdata.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2018 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace CP\Register\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

/**
 * Install data
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface {

    /**
     * CustomerSetupFactory
     * @var CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    protected $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * $attributeSetFactory
     * @var AttributeSetFactory
     */
    private $attributeSetFactory;

    /**
     * initiate object
     * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     * @param AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
    CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory, AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }

    /**
     * install data method
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context) {

        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);
        /**
         * customer registration form default field mobile number
         */
        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'documents', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'ID Documents',
            'input' => 'file',
            'required' => true,
            'visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => false,
            'sort_order' => 1000,
            'position' => 1000,
            'system' => 0,
        ]);
        //add attribute to attribute set
        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'documents')
                ->addData([
            'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
            'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
            'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_create', 'customer_address_edit', 'customer_register_address', 'checkout_register', 'adminhtml_checkout'],
        ]);
        $attribute->save();
    }

}
```

After that in edit.phtml file i write code for that

```
<fieldset class="fieldset create account">
    <legend class="legend"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Additional Information') ?></span></legend>
    <p>
    <div class="fileadd">
        <label for="FileAdd" class="label">
            <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Id Document') ?></span>
        </label>
        <div class="control">
            <input type="file" name="documents" id="documents" value="<?php echo $mediaPath."customer/".$block->escapeHtml($block->getCustomer()->getCustomAttribute('documents')->getValue()); ?>"" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('ID Document') ?>"><?php //echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getCustomer()->getCustomAttribute('documents')->getValue());?></input>
           <!--  <?php //echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getCustomer()->getCustomAttribute('documents')->getValue()) ?> -->
        </div>
    </div>
</p>
</fieldset>
```

Now i want to get value here but i don't get

[image]

I want to like show this in account edit information

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple anchor tag.

```
<?php

$customerMedia = $block->getBaseUrl() . 'pub/media/customer';
$customer_attribute_value = $customer->getData('customer_attribute_code');
$filePath = $customerMedia . $customer_attribute_value;

?>
<?php if ($customer_attribute_value) : ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $filePath ?>">Your Document</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**Note:** If your file type is image only, you can use `<img src='' />`. If you have different file type such as pdf, then you can show a sample document icon and put it in an anchor tag.

Comment: no you don't get my question here i give link of image i want to like as https://prnt.sc/j1mq66

Comment: You have to create custom preview section for this. I have added a note to the answer. You can read that.

Comment: @DineshYadav If I upload a file like this, abcd.pdf , then it creates folder like this - /pub/media/customer/a/b/ then how can i get pdf path